# How to store the values that are passed between activities in android and use those values for further calculations

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to develop an android mobile app which requires some calculations regarding an invoice. When I need to add items to invoice I need to go to another form(that is another activity) by clicking a button. After fill that form, only the value of that particular item should come to the invoice. Likewise if I need X number of items to purchase, I need to fill that Items form X times. And the amount for each item should display in the invoice separately.Finally by clicking a button in the invoice, can be able to find the total amount of the values in the invoice.

This is what I actually try, But I could Only pass one value to invoice form from items activity. When I click the add button again  and fill item form and come to invoice, previously entered value is vanished. I need to keep all the values in the invoice form and finally need to calculate the total in invoice. 
    Please help me to solve this problem. I've read many articles and questions regarding this, but I couldn't find a better way to solve this problem. I highly appreciate your kind help..

first XML file is activity_invoice.XML file
Second Invoice Activity, third is activity_items.xml and  fourth is Items Activity

```
  <!--Click this button to goto Items Activity-->

                   <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addItemBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add a New Item"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshapes"
                     />

                  <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/valueofItemText"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Sub Value"
                 />

        <!--Get the final value of Item activity here-->

                  <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/valueofItemEdit"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:hint="Sub Value"
                 />


            <!--Button to find the discount of invoice-->

                   <Button
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceDiscountBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:text="Total"
                    />

    <!--Enter the discount value of Invoivce activity-->

                  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editDiscount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    />

        <!--get the total sum of all items values in this Invoice activity taken from items Activity-->

                   <Button
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceTotaltBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:text="Total"
                    />

    <!--Display the total of invoice-->

                  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceTotal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    />





      public class Invoice extends AppCompatActivity {        


        Button addItemBtn, discountBtn, totalBtn;
        TextView billedtoUser;
        EditText eSubTotal, eDiscount, eTotal;

        double invoiceDiscount, subTotalValue, invoiceTotal, subtractDis;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_invoice);
            setTitle("Invoice");



            /*----------------------Add item description--------------------*/

            addItemBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItemBtn);
            addItemBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    addItemDescription();
                }
            });



             /*-----------------get Items Activity Value to Invoice Activity -------------------------*/
            eSubTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueofItemText);
            Intent myIntent = getIntent();
            if (myIntent.hasExtra("ItemValue")) {
                valueofItemText.setText(" $" + myIntent.getStringExtra("ItemValue"));
            }


        /*--------------------define addItemDescription------------------------*/

        private void addItemDescription() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Invoice.this, Items.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }




       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

                  <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="576dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.03"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Item Code"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#FF042A51" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/itemCode"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.12"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />
                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Item Name"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#FF042A51" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/itemName"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.12"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:textColor="#FF0D68C4"
                            android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />
                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fourthLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView5"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Quantity"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#FF042A51" />

<!--Enter the number of Items purchasing -->
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/quantity"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.11"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:textColor="#FF0D68C4"
                            android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/sixthLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">



                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Unit Cost"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#FF042A51" />


<!--Enter value of one item-->
                           <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/unitCost"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.12"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/seventhLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Discount (%)"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#FF042A51" />

<!--Enter discount for items If discount is there-->
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/discount"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.12"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />
                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/eigthLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

       <!--Button to find the amount for items-->                
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/amountbtn"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Line Value"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#FF042A51" />

    <!--Display the amount of Items-->
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/amount"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.12"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />
                    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Submit this value to Invoice Activity using this button-->
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/submitDescription"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Done"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:minWidth="20dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>






 public class Items extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button descriptionSubmitBtn, finalAmountBtn;
    EditText iCode, iName;

    EditText qty, uCost, discount, famountText;

    double unitCost, discountValue, quantity;
    double quntUniCost, subtractDis, finalTotalAmount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_items_description);
        setTitle("Item Description"); 

        descriptionSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitDescription);
        iCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemCode);
        iName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemName);

        /*--------------------variables to find discount for each item---------------------------*/
        qty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        uCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unitCost);
        discount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.discount);
        famountText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        finalAmountBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amountbtn);


        /*------------------calculateDiscount-------------------------------------*/

        finalAmountBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                calculateDiscount();
            }
        });


        /*--------------------------sendData----------------------------------------*/
        descriptionSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendData();
            }
        });

    }


    /*------------------------------define sendData method-----------------------------*/

    private void sendData() {
        String str1 = famountText.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Items.this,Invoice.class);
        intent.putExtra("ItemValue", str1); //key Value pair
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    /*--------------------define calculateDiscount method-------------------------------*/
    private void calculateDiscount() {
        quantity = Double.parseDouble((qty.getText().toString()));
        unitCost = Double.parseDouble(uCost.getText().toString());
        discountValue = Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString());




        quntUniCost = quantity * unitCost;
        subtractDis = 100 - discountValue;
        finalTotalAmount = (subtractDis * quntUniCost) / 100;

        //round to two decimal points
        famountText.setText(String.format("%.2f", finalTotalAmount));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `listView` and add items to that list and display them in invoice activity.  Currently you are passing one value in `intent.putextra ();` which is refreshed when you again call the invoice activity as `onCreate()` is being called and you view is created again. 
Another option can be using the `SharedPreferences` to store your items and then display them in the invoice activity.

Comment: @Kash let me know if you need any further assistance. Thanks

Comment: thank you for the help ... I've understood the concept that you mentioned, but I have no clear  idea to how to use this, please if you can explain me a little bit using a code snipt

Comment: You can change the flow of adding the items. User can add items on the Items Activity as much as he wants and then go to the Invoice activity.After adding one item the fields gets cleared and then user can add another item.  Why going back and forth for adding the items. This is a suggestion. let me know what you think.

Comment: yep, I thought about it, but want to calculate the final value of items. For example if user A buys 10 pens and 12 books , then these values should pass to the Invoice Activity.  And to enter data for pens and books the Items form need two times. That's actually what I want is..

Comment: you can show the notification showing that item added to cart, and then reset the form for the user for another selection. There is no need of closing and reopening the activities by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153292/discussion-between-malik-ahsan-and-kash).

Comment: If that was helpful,  mark the answer as correct and up vote it plz.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I saw in your code is that you are using input integer or decimal.. So even to pass it you must think about the type. Also , after you do calculation and before you set the value to TextView You must convert to String. You cannot do any mathematical calculation like adding , subtracting, etc using string.

To get Int Intent//// getIntExtra("key", 0);
to get String /// getStringEtra("key");
to get double /// do research

In Invoice Class you have made explicit intent without passing any value to the intent.. basically, every time you start new intent without ending your session which has values, then you must always pass the values between two intent,,

First you pass value to the next activity , then you get the value from intent and do whatever calculation you want do and again result you must pass to first activity using intent, again from the first activity you must get the value from intent which you pass from second activity and again send that value and new value to the second activity,, i know its kinda heck-tic but worth to give  a try,,

```html
////ActivityOne.java

     public void onClick(View view) {  
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);  
              i.putExtra("Value1", 1);    
              // callback via this code  
              startActivity(i);  
             } 
       
      ////ActivityTwo.java

            eSubTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueofItemText);
            Intent myIntent = getIntent();
            if (myIntent.hasExtra("Value1")) {
                valueofItemText.setText(" $" + String.ValueOf(myIntent.getIntExtra("ItemValue", 0)));
            }
      
       public void onClick(View view) {  
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityOne.class);  
              i.putExtra("Answer1", "Android By Irufan");   
              startActivity(i);  
             } 

    ////ActivityOne.java

           String answer1 ;
            Intent i = getIntent();
            answerIntent = i.getStringExtra("Answer1");

     public void onClick(View view) {  
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);  
              i.putExtra("Value2", 1);
              i.putExtra("Answer1", answerIntent);
             
              startActivity(i);  
             }
```